# Unable to install Ubuntu on on Sony Vaio Y Series E-450

Tags: 11.10, installation, vaio, sony

Hi guys I am not able to install Ubuntu 11.10/SUSE on my new Sony Vaio, All the Linux distributions get hanged on the Initial USB boot saying "Syslinux 4.04 EDD XYZ"

Can anyone suggest how can I proceed with the installation.

Configuation of system is as below:
AMD E450
6320 GPU
AMD VT Enabled
2GB RAM
320 GB HDD

I have tried 32 bit and AMD64 bit versions of Ubuntu.

thanks
Shakti

Comment: How are you creating the USB boot stick - unetbootin?

Answer (score 1):

If the computer has an optical drive (CD/DVD drive) you can try burning a CD for it. Some computers can be touchy about USB booting still.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Vaio Y Series and have installed Ubuntu 12.04 without any problem. 1st I made my Usb installer using Universal USB Boot Pendrive and USB boot my notebook by pressing F11. Everything went well and I had to turn my wifi when it was installing driver cos it froze.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue with mine.  You have to use the cd and then open the cd and click the option that has the ubuntu logo next to it, can't remember the name.  I couldn't get my Vaio to boot from the USB stick.  Warning:  you'll have problems with the wireless card.  Working on that right now.